# Linq Left Outer Join With newest datetime in right side

Tags: c#, .net, linq, left-join

I have "Orders" table where its primary key is "OrderId ":

```
OrderId | OrderName
------- | ----------
1       | Order X
2       | Order Y  
3       | Order Z
```

and "OrderDetails" table where its primary key is "OrderDetailsId " foreign key is 'OrderId":

```
OrderDetailsId | OrderId | ItemId | DeliveryDate
-------------- | ------- | ------ | ------------
10             | 1       |   AA   | 1/1/2010
20             | 1       |   BB   | 1/1/2013
30             | 2       |   CC   | 1/1/2012
40             | 2       |   CC   | 1/1/2014
```

Each order has ZERO or more order details, each order detail has specific delivery date.

We want to get all the orders, whether they have order details or not, and mark just one order as VIP if it has the order detail that has the maximum "delivery date"

This is the expected output:

```
OrderId | OrderName | IsVIP
------- | --------- | -----
1       | Order X   |  NO
2       | Order Y   |  YES
3       | Order Z   |  NO (since it has no order details)
```

That's because the maximum delivery date is for OrderDetailsId = 40 which belongs to OrderId = 2

How to accomplish this using the most readable LINQ code

Comment: Did you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: What if there are two orders that have details with the same max date?

Comment: @juharr We've constraints that prevent multiple order details from having the same date even for different orders. This is enforced before inserting any new record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you have `OrderDetails` property in `orders` collection (if so then @juharr's answer is correct). But, if they are not then you can make use of `group join` like this:-

```
var result = from o in orders
             join od in orderDetails
             on o.OrderId equals od.OrderId into g
             select new { 
              OrderId = o.OrderId, 
              OrderName = o.OrderName,
              IsVIP = g.Any(x => x.DeliveryDate == orderDetails.Max(z => z.DeliveryDate)) 
                                                 ? "Yes" : "No" 
               };
```

Here is an example [**Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ApGBa9) with `linq-to-objects`.

Answer (score 2):

Use navigation properties.  Note this will set `IsVIP` to "YES" for all orders that contain an order detail with the max delivery date.

```
var query = from order in db.Orders
            select new
            {
                order.OrderId,
                order.Name,
                IsVIP = order.OrderDetails.Any(
                        od => od.DeliveryDate == db.OrderDetails.Max(x => x.DeliveryDate))
                    ? "YES"
                    : "NO"
            };
```